# Top level opaque type with same underlying type and identical extensions methods

Tags: scala, scala-3

I ran into an issue when defining opaque types with identical underlying types and extension methods, e.g.:

```
opaque type HandleA = Int

object HandleA:

  def apply(value: Int): HandleA = value

extension (handle: HandleA) @targetName("HandleA_value") def value: Int = handle

opaque type HandleB = Int

object HandleB:

  def apply(value: Int): HandleB = value

extension (handle: HandleB) @targetName("HandleB_value") def value: Int = handle
```

When the two definitions resided in the same file, the code compiled, but when defined in two separate files, the code did not compile with the following error:

> value is already defined as method value in ...

Is there a way to create these definitions at the same level in separate files somehow?

I tried wrapping the definitions in objects in two separate files and making them available at the top-level of the package by exporting them

```
// HandleA.scala

object HandleAWrap:
  opaque type HandleA = Int

  object HandleA:

    def apply(value: Int): HandleA = value

    extension (handle: HandleA) @targetName("HandleA_value") def value: Int = handle
```

```
// HandleB.scala

object HandleBWrap:
  opaque type HandleB = Int

  object HandleB:

    def apply(value: Int): HandleB = value

    extension (handle: HandleB) @targetName("HandleB_value") def value: Int = handle
```

```
// Lib.scala

export HandleAWrap.*
export HandleBWrap.*
```

But doing this I got a different compilation error along the lines of:

> cyclic reference via <import>

due to the usage of `@targetName` to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Shouldn't everything be under the `object`? I mea' both the type and the extension methods? The documentation show it this way and it might be important for the scope.

Comment: (https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-opaque-types.html)

Comment: @GaëlJ I gave it a try but once I made the relevant extensions available at the top-level of the package I still got compilation errors for double definitions, or cyclic reference via <import> if using **targetName**.

Comment: _once I made the relevant extensions available at the top-level of the package_ can you update your post with what you tried, I'm not sure I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Defining opaque types at top-level as is presented in the first example (and as the question title suggests) is anti-pattern.

The objective is to confine the scope where the opaque type translation is understood, typically in a singleton (`HandleAWrap`) as you do in your second example.

2/ extension methods on the opaque type should be placed in companion object of the type. This makes them visible to anyone using the type, without being explicitly imported. Again, the second example is correct, not the first one.

3/ `@targetName` in your second example is not needed, since extension methods are defined within `object HandleA` and `object HandleB` respectively and do not collide.

File `handleA.scala`:

```scala
package x

object HandleAWorld:
  opaque type HandleA = Int
  object HandleA:
    def apply(value:Int): HandleA = value
    extension (handle:HandleA) def value : Int = handle
```

File `handleB.scala` likewise for `HandleB`.

File `lib.scala`:

```scala
package x

export HandleAWorld.*
export HandleBWorld.*
```

Usage :

```scala
Welcome to Scala 3.2.2 (11.0.18, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import x.*

scala> val a = HandleA(42)
val a: x.HandleAWorld.HandleA = 42

scala> val b = HandleB(3)
val b: x.HandleBWorld.HandleB = 3

scala> a.value
val res0: Int = 42

scala> b.value
val res1: Int = 3
```

4/ Even in presence of `@targetName`, the example above compiles.
The `cyclic reference via <import>` error you encountered is probably not related to opaque types nor `@targetName`.